# akka amqp heartbeat option and fault tolerance

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, amqp, akka

So I'm not seeing a way to easily tune the connection factory for the 
AMQP module.  It's embedded deep enough in a package private class 
that short of explicit structural type casting, it doesn't seem like 
there is a way.   I need to enable heartbeat functionality on it using 
a setter.

Now, even if there is a way to set it (I don't see how), the AMQP 
actor doesn't seem to have a way to reconnect in case of a shutdown 
exception, which is thrown when the heartbeat fails. 
Let me know if the above observations are ok?  I'd really like to 
continue using the akka amqp module, but I'll have to rewrite it using 
raw amqp-client if the above isn't possible. 
Thanks a lot. 
Ilya

Comment: Are you still using akka-amqp? It was eliminated a while ago, the suggested replacement is akka-camel.